# UI elements slide after showing MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, window

My app has no status bar and has ui elements in full screen. (0,0) - (480, 320).
The problem is, after I show MFMessageComposeViewController by using presentModalViewController: and dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:, all ui elements have been slided downward.

I checked the frame and bounds of window which the ui elements are put, but both of them are correct value origin(0,0) size(480,320) but the frame and bounds of window.rootViewController.view is size(480,300).

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this it will solve the problem, reset the frame after dismissing the message controller

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{

    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:

            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:

            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to solve this problem without changing frame manually?

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can add in view controller's viewDidLoad method the following line:

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```